# Unable to Convert encrypted Response data in View Results Tree in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, apache-tika, jmeter-plugins

I am running a script where the Response Data is Encoded. To convert to HTML/Plain Text. I imported tika-app-1.7.jar file to `<jmeter>/lib`

Restarted Jmeter.(2.13)
But still unable to get the Text Converted

Could anyone please help me on that. It still showing the below and no Response data in View Results Tree got converted to HTML.

---

Missing tika-app.jar in classpath. Unable to convert to plain text this kind of document.
Download the tika-app-x.x.jar file from http://tika.apache.org/download.html
And put the file in `<JMeter>/lib` directory.

---

Answer (score 1):

Apache Tika won't deal with encoded content, it is for text representation of documents (line Word, Excel, Powerpoint, PDF, etc.) If you're totally sure you're getting the document in one of [Tika supported types](https://tika.apache.org/1.4/formats.html) as a response be aware that **JMeter restart is required to pick up tika jar**.

For more information on dealing with binary data in JMeter see [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/what-every-performance-tester-should-know-about-extracting-data-files-jmeter)